# ImportError: No module named 'xx' in mac and linux

Tags: python

I am right now using the mac and trying to use the module pypng. I have installed the module from pip install pypng. It works well. However when I run my application python test.py (where inside test.py has 'import png'), it gives me a error saying 'ImportError:No module named png'.

However when I go into the python environment from command line, I type 'import png', it works without a error, why is that. I even restart the computer, but still in trouble.

when I installed pypng module, it tells me it is install in /Users/abc1/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages, where inside this directory I can find the png.py and png.pyc.

---

when i print sys.path, this is the output, looks like it didn't load the png package from /Users/abc1/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages. how do i solve it

```
['/Applications/Blender/blender.app/Contents/Resources/2.76/scripts/addons_contrib', '/Applications/Blender/blender.app/Contents/Resources/2.76/scripts/addons', '/Applications/Blender/blender.app/Contents/Resources/2.76/scripts/modules', '/Applications/Blender/blender.app/Contents/Resources/2.76/scripts/startup', '/Applications/Blender/blender.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/2.76/scripts/modules', '/Applications/Blender/blender.app/Contents/Resources/2.76/python/lib/python34.zip', '/Applications/Blender/blender.app/Contents/Resources/2.76/python/lib/python3.4', '/Applications/Blender/blender.app/Contents/Resources/2.76/python/lib/python3.4/plat-darwin', '/Applications/Blender/blender.app/Contents/Resources/2.76/python/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload', '/Applications/Blender/blender.app/Contents/Resources/2.76/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages', '/Applications/Blender/blender.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/2.76/scripts/freestyle/modules', '/Applications/Blender/blender.app/Contents/Resources/2.76/scripts/addons/modules', '/Users/xisizhe/Library/Application Support/Blender/2.76/scripts/addons/modules']
```

Comment: in your script, just before the `import png` print the python path with `import sys
print sys.path` (two lines of code) and check if the output matches when run in the python command line

Comment: You use virtual environment? pypng installed into system packages or into environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you installed `png` to your python environment in the command line but not the environment you run your script. Try to use `python batch.py` in command line, or append `/Users/abc1/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages` to `sys.path`.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder. I can see where the problem is, now I solve it

Answer (score -1):

Do you have a directory in your project that is named png? If so python will try to import it instead of the actual module

Comment: this is my current command. /Applications/Blender/blender.app/Contents/MacOS/blender -b scene.blend -P batch.py. The executed batch.py is in a directory where no png directory is found or the parents directory has no png named directory

Comment: when I installed pypng module, it tells me it is install in /Users/abc1/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages, where inside this directory I can find the png.py and png.pyc

Comment: This should be a comment.